# Disable USB Device Programmatically

Tags: vb.net

I've got a HID device that I need to programmatically disable in VB.NET. I downloaded the WMICodeCreator, and used that to generate the code to ID my device, but the code creator doesn't give me access to any methods to disable the device (only query for it's status).

How to disable the device?

```
Imports System
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace WMISample

    Public Class MyWMIQuery

        Public Overloads Shared Function Main() As Integer

            Try
                Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( _
                        "root\CIMV2", _
                        "SELECT * FROM Win32_USBDevice WHERE DeviceID =      'USB\\VID_0596&PID_0586\\1B0033000251343439343037'") 

                For Each queryObj As ManagementObject in searcher.Get()

                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------")
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_USBDevice instance")
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------")
                    Console.WriteLine("DeviceID: {0}", queryObj("DeviceID"))
                Next
            Catch err As ManagementException
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " & err.Message)
            End Try
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: I have used [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21503/Hardware-Helper-Library-for-C) in the past. You may able to adopt it in VB.NET. But if not, I suggest you take a look at [Pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/) for further information. If this helps, I'll post as an answer.